# How to orchestrate well?

Tags: theory, orchestration

I am starting a concerto, and one of the problems is about the orchestration. I have not studied orchestration, do not have an orchestration book, or any orchestral knowledge from a theoretical standpoint. I am not asking for a full book, only the basics of orchestration, as in, what do you want to aim for, what things should you avoid like the black plague, etc, and how do you balance between tuttis, only strings, only winds, etc,(in my case, tutti, only piano, only orchestra, and specific combinations). What are the absolute basics of orchestration?

Comment: The absolute basics are still too much for an SE answer I think. But there’s a book that’s public domain and available free online written by Rimsky-Korsakov on orchestration.

Comment: What you're asking is not unlike "I'm starting a marathon competition, how do I run?". With all due respect, I wouldn't even begin to think "I am starting a concerto" considering what is being asked. Even before that, I'd ask myself something like "Do I have enough knowledge and experience to begin *to think* I could be able to write a concerto?". That said, nobody says you shouldn't do it. But consider that even not "famed" composers began to write concertos after *years* (sometimes decades) of composition and orchestration. Rimsky-Korsakov is good advice, then keep studying and practicing.

Comment: @musicamante Rachmaninoff was a,"famed" composer, and he wrote his first concerto as his opus 1, before any solo piano or chamber music. I know I am not Rachmaninoff(not anywhere near) but that means that it can be done, even without any experience.

Comment: @Gregory Very true. It's just a bit much to enumerate all of that extremely broad information on orchestration as one answer - people have written entire books on that subject, it wouldn't be possible to answer summarily. Do you have specific concerns about some part of orchestration? You could break this up into multiple questions...

Comment: @Gregory Don't be confused by published Opus numbers and actual studying experience. Rachmaninoff composed that first concerto after at least 8 years of conservatory (obviously including theory and harmony), of which at least 3 spent studying counterpoint and composition (which doesn't mean he didn't begin studying those subjects even before on his own). He obviously wrote a lot of piano, chamber and orchestral music before that point, just like any composer; the fact that all those works are not published (or are not catalogued *before* the concerto) is completely irrelevant.

Comment: There’s not really a link between what Rachmaninov did and what is on-topic here at Music.SE.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree. I just wanted to point out that "Op. 1" does **not** mean "my first [orchestral] composition without any experience".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any answers would need to be far too long to fit here.

Comment: Seems you're trying to run marathons when all you've tried is walking downstairs! If you need to ask a question such as this, it's telling that you're nowhere near ready, and need to cut your teeth on far more basic music - maybe for several years. Sorry!

Comment: @Gregory There are a lot of voices here rightly pointing out that a concerto is a rather ambitious "first step" without having orchestration knowledge. I just wanted to offer a word of encouragement that you shouldn't necessarily abandon it. As G.K. Chesterton said, "Anything worth doing is worth doing badly," and you can learn a lot from mistakes. Also, many major Hollywood soundtracks are created by one person hammering out the basics at the piano, and someone else doing the labor of orchestration. By all means, jot down your ideas. Then, maybe find someone knowledgeable to...

Comment: ... to do the orchestration and explain to you why they make the choices they do, or even to walk you through doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to study existing scores, and get a library of remembered sounds stored in your brain.  You have to know what an oboe and a clarinet sound like together, or those with flutes added.  You need to be able to imagine how bright a violin will sound at a certain note, and how loud a timpani sounds in a concert hall (as opposed to a sampled instrument on a DAW).

All instruments have a kind of timbre spectrum-- the quality of sound changes as you vary pitch and volume.

In short if you want to do composition, you need to do the things you haven't done.  Sorry, no shortcuts.

**As a beginning orchestrator, if you aren't going through everything ever written by Mozart first, then I'd humbly say you're doing it wrong. :)**

Comment: Well, maybe "everything ever written by Mozart" is a bit too much... Especially if we also consider *anything* he wrote, including [**those**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_and_scatology) letters he wrote to his cousin Maria... Or maybe not? ;-)

Comment: Tish I'm tea.  :P